# Cannot open emacs

Tags: emacs

Whenever I try to open emacs, it opens and then close agian.

In the terminal I get the following error

```
X protocol error: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) on protocol request 139
When compiled with GTK, Emacs cannot recover from X disconnects.
This is a GTK bug: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85715
For details, see etc/PROBLEMS.

(emacs:10357): GLib-WARNING **: g_main_context_prepare() called recursively from within a source's check() or prepare() member.

(emacs:10357): GLib-WARNING **: g_main_context_check() called recursively from within a source's check() or prepare() member.
Fatal error 6: Aborted
Backtrace:
emacs[0x4f74cb]
emacs[0x4dcf3e]
emacs[0x4f7513]
emacs[0x4b219b]
emacs[0x4b420c]
emacs[0x4b426d]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6(_XError+0x12b)[0x7feae3f0e54b]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6(+0x3b5e7)[0x7feae3f0b5e7]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6(+0x3b695)[0x7feae3f0b695]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6(_XEventsQueued+0x55)[0x7feae3f0bfc5]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6(XPending+0x4d)[0x7feae3efe12d]
...
[1]    10357 abort (core dumped)  emacs
```

Comment: Did you read the error message? It seems to be kind of a bug which is offtopic here.

Comment: This is a GTK bug: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85715